# Why did the English dub of Naruto stop?

Tags: naruto, anime-production

Naruto and few episodes of Naruto Shippuuden are dubbed in English. Then it suddenly stopped. And also, few episodes used to be broadcasted in Cartoon Network, and that also stopped. Why has this happened?

Comment: It takes time to dub an anime and since Naruto is still on-going, they are probably on the process of dubbing it or they are still waiting for Japan's official release before they can release an english dubbed version.

Comment: Naruto shippuuden dubs ussualy come around in packs of 4 with a interval of around 2-4months . Exact reason I do no know

Answer (score 7):

Naruto aired on Cartoon Network and Naruto Shippuden aired on Disney XD. Apparently, Disney XD has dropped Shippuden from it's lineup but the Anime continues and episodes can be viewed on [CrunchyRoll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden) or [Viz Anime](http://www.vizanime.com/naruto-shippuden), though the episodes are subtitled not dubbed.

Looks like, for those wanting Dubbed Naruto Shippuden, getting the DVDs/Blu-Rays is currently the only option.

**Update:** Stream the latest **English dubbed versions** (legally) from [Amazon Instant Video](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BIVRTQ).

Comment: Naruto shippudin dubbed available in DVD's?

Comment: Naruto is currently re-airing on Cartoon Network on Saturday nights as part of Toonami, right after Bleach.