# Where can I watch naruto shippuden 487 - 500 dubbed

Tags: naruto

I have watched up to episode 486 dubbed on AnimeLab but doesn't have anymore. Where am I able to watch the remaining episodes.

ps - I live in Australia not sure if it matters though

Comment: The [last DVD set (containing 487–500) for Australia](https://www.madman.com.au/catalogue/view/47793/naruto-shippuden-collection-38-eps-487500) was released on August 7, 2019. I assume they delay the streaming due to [preferring the DVD sales](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/47002/2516) first, so my suggestion is to wait for now... or buy the DVD.

Comment: Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.